# HTML/CSS/JS: Can an invisible form intercept (hijack) user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, iframe

I heard someone mention that one could theoretically position an invisible iframe on top of content and receive the input that someone wants to put in a form. How would this be possible and not get suspicion? It scares me...

Comment: Don't be scared. We're here for you!

Comment: This isn't restricted to just HTML/CSS. I believe Flash can also be employed for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible! It's called **clickjacking**, and is very real indeed. Check this out for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Michal Zalewski, of Google, has a theoretically example (Source: [Page 1](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9115818/FAQ_Clickjacking_should_you_be_worried_), [Page 2](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9115818/FAQ_Clickjacking_should_you_be_worried_?taxonomyId=17&pageNumber=2)):

> A malicious page in domain A may
>   create an IFRAME pointing to an
>   application in domain B, to which the
>   user is currently authenticated with
>   cookies," Zalewski said in a message
>   to a mailing list on Thursday. "The
>   top-level page may then cover portions
>   of the IFRAME with other visual
>   elements to seamlessly hide everything
>   but a single UI button in domain B,
>   such as 'delete all items,' 'click to
>   add Bob as a friend,' etc. It may then
>   provide [its] own, misleading UI that
>   implies that the button serves a
>   different purpose and is a part of
>   site A, inviting the user to click it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this without drawing suspicion, *someone* will always notice.  If you're not a standard user, I would recommend you try downloading noscript (a firefox plugin).  It prevents any website not on your personal whitelist from running javascript.  This should alleviate a lot of your worries!  I hope!  I know it makes *me* feel better.

Answer (score 0):

In the realm of possibilities, there are many stupid ideas. :-)

Theoretically, you can hijack a form and place a region that captures input. This is not a simple exercise, as you need to mimic the form or have the user step outside of the security box of the browser. It is far easier to phish with a look alike form than do this.

I see someone mentioned clickjacking, which hijacks the click event. Overall, this is different from the form capture, although it could be used to cover a button once a form was filled in. Once again, there it is similar to a phish attack, as you are hitting their site. Without this misdirection, they can't inject the JavaScript necessary to make this work.

What is your real concern? That someone can hit your site and be hijacked without another site on top? Unlikely. That people can be fooled. Well, PT Barnum taught us there is one born every day.